# Enabling/Disabling certain types of Push Messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Im working on a magazine app where user can view certain variety of products.My app includes 4 variety of push notifications concerning four variants of products.Is it possible to add an option in UI for users to disable push notifications for certain messages while able to recieve the notifications he wish to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it from the app level itself, since the push notifications that go to an app are controlled at the OS level (so push notifications for the app, but regardless of what for)

However, you can setup tags (or something) on your server so then the app enables/disabled the server to send notifications for a specific topic.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of the approach where users can enable/disable certain notificationsYeah, Iwe where the user query to the server and will configure the requested notification to a specific user.This approach would be fine right?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to have a "Notification Center" of some sort on your server to enable/disable topics, which then send a set of notifications to a phone/account.